# Is it possible to use generics but require an specific parent type?

Tags: java

I want to create a class `MyMap<T>`, where `T` **must** derive from `MyAbstractClass`.
 
`MyMap` will then create and manage an array of  whatever type it is. `MyMap.getPos(0,0)` should return an object of the type `T`, Not `MyAbstractClass`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
MyMap<T extends MyAbstractClass>
```

It will force the generic type to extend `MyAbstractClass`, but otherwise it will work exactly as if you had just supplied `T` as the class.  Specifically, your functions will return `T`.

Comment: So simple that I'm embarassed for asking. Thanks. Will accept when allowed.

Comment: I usually have to read the manual when I do anything like this with generics, so don't feel too bad!

Answer (score 5):

Use `extends` like this:

```
MyMap<T extends MyAbstractClass>
```

Answer (score 4):

To put the restriction on `T`

```
MyMap<T extends MyAbstractClass> {
    ....
}
```

To create the array, you have two options. One is to create a `MyAbstractClass[]` and cast to `T` in your methods. The other is to take a `Class<T>` in your constructor and use `Array.newInstance(class, size)`.

Comment: you people need to stop posting the same answer over and over, this is the 4th same exact answer already

Comment: @Mr D: Read my second paragraph. No one else provides that information, and it was half the question. I wouldn't have posted if someone else had the second half.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
MyMap<T extends MyAbstractClass>
```